# Getting Google plus profile image

Tags: java, google-plus

I have been developing a Java language application.

Now i am trying to show the logged in user photograph as part of the user data, but i dont seem to get it right.

Through UserService i am getting the user id, and with the user id and my application api key, i am trying to build the image url to load it into my application.

But it isnt working.

The url i am building is : https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{USER_ID}?fields=image&key={API_KEY}

But i keep getting the same error :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate     the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I have enabled as well the following API in Google Developers Console:

```
Drive API   
Drive SDK   
Google Cloud SQL    
Google Compute Engine   
Google Picker API
Google+ API
```

Can anyone lend me a hand on this?. Sorry if i waste your time with something obvious.

Comment: You can get image url directly in `Json` file , but I don't know Java

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using the right value for the API key. They're under Public API access in the Credentials section of the developer console and should look like something like this: AIzaSyC2WWuM97gdij5k5uRduLFeL3LuURBvFpo - make sure it's of that form, and associated with the project you have enabled the API for.

Comment: Are you using a numeric ID for the user? The string "me" wont work with a public access key. When you say you tried it, I presume you mean you went to the developer console and checked the key, not that you tried the one in my answer (which isn't active!).

Comment: Yes, i went to the developer console, checked the key, copied it, and tried to use it in my app without success. The user is a numeric id. Is there any problem with that? I am by no means, able to change it.

Comment: no, numeric ID is correct. 1 - Have you tried it with multiple different users, just to make sure its not something user specific. 2 - are you sure the key constrains are met (e.g. if it is a browser key, are you on an allowed referrer, if a server key on an allowed IP address)?

Comment: Hi Ian. Yes i have tried with different users. It is a browser key, and i am on an allowed referer. Thank you for your time and resources

Comment: Can you try regenerating the key in the developer console (will give you a new string), and see if that makes any difference? I know there is some caching on enabled APIs associated with a key, but I would have thought they would have cleared by now.

Comment: Can you try making the call via cURL or similar, to make sure nothing is getting messed up when you create the URL?

Comment: I deleted last comment. I will try what you tell me and will answer back if i get any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and nothing changed. I keep getting the same error. I think i will try with the classic way, oAuth2.0  authentication. Thank you for your time, pacience and resources.